# Can you call a WCF service from an SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf

And what would the return data look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, it is possible to call any WS from the **stored procedure** in MS SQL. It is very similiar to calling Web Services from C# or other .NET language. [Here](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2008/11/11/calling-a-web-service-from-sql-server-2005/) you can find more detailed scenario.